# How to tern on sentry Profiling on self-hosted version?

Tags: profiling, sentry

I have a self hosted sentry, any idea how to set up profiling ?

I have fing relevant comment here
https://discord.com/channels/621778831602221064/1024798907496140820/1141296160812843048
but still have no idea what to do